# Dlang: Const objects having value semantics cannot be used in rhs of assignment

Tags: types, d

The following snippet is a compilation error saying that the variable `c` of type `const(B)` cannot be converted to `ulong`.

```
import std.typecons;

void main()
{
    Typedef!(ulong, -1, "B") b;
    const(Typedef!(ulong, -1, "B")) c = 0;
    b = c;
}
```

However, the equivalent version using the underlying plain type `ulong` compiles fine.

Isn't the idea of a `Typedef` that it should work exactly like the underlying type without allowing implicit conversions to/from the underlying type? Why is there a difference in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Typedef` simply isn't written with const in mind. It should offer a function that takes the const and assigns to the payload, but doesn't.

So a bug caused by author oversight. tbh, I don't take Phobos' Typedef very seriously, it is a bizarre thing. I prefer to just write structs for my types myself.